# How do I reattach to a screen session when the socket is there, but screen won't use it?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I've seen [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/58525/how-do-i-reconnect-to-a-lost-screen-detached-missing-socket) and [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/283684/why-cant-i-attach-a-screen-session), but neither of them apply to me.  I have the socket file in /var/run/screen and I own it - but screen -list doesn't recognize it and allow me to connect.    How can I recover this session?

```
tom@host~ $ ls /var/run/screen/S-tom/
total 0
prw------- 1 tom people 0 Jul  2 19:07 3954.pts-0.host

tom@host ~ $ screen -list
No Sockets found in /home/tom/.screen.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set the `SCREENDIR` environment variable to `/var/run/screen`. You should then be able to list and connect.

Assuming `sh` compatible shell:

`export SCREENDIR="/var/run/screen"`

From `man 1 screen`

```
ENVIRONMENT
   COLUMNS        Number of columns on the terminal (overrides termcap entry).
   HOME           Directory in which to look for .screenrc.
   LINES          Number of lines on the terminal (overrides termcap entry).
   LOCKPRG        Screen lock program.
   NETHACKOPTIONS Turns on nethack option.
   PATH           Used for locating programs to run.
   SCREENCAP      For customizing a terminal's TERMCAP value.
   SCREENDIR      Alternate socket directory.
   SCREENRC       Alternate user screenrc file.
   SHELL          Default shell program for opening windows (default "/bin/sh").
   STY            Alternate socket name.
   SYSSCREENRC    Alternate system screenrc file.
   TERM           Terminal name.
   TERMCAP        Terminal description.
   WINDOW         Window number of a window (at creation time).
```

Comment: I have no idea why I had to do this, but it worked!  Thank you.